# What happened to everyone else after the ending of Death Note?

Tags: death-note

I am not sure if I have asked this question before but deleted it, but I was just wondering if Matsuda and the other detectives found out that

> Light died

If they did:

- Would they have made an investigation to see if somebody else had a Death Note and wrote his name in it?
- Did they think that he wrote his own name with the paper he had from the Death Note?
- Did they think that Ryuk wrote his name in the Death Note?
- Or did they just go back to their regular lives, and

> tell Misa and Light's family that Light was Kira and that he died?

Those are the only options I have in my head, so I was just wondering if any of those options happened.

Comment: Isn't misa die?

Comment: I am not sure if she dies in the anime or manga, but in the live action death note movies she dies

Comment: @Ratharax I appreciate your intent, but spoiler tags don't work in titles. I'll take the liberty of making an edit of my own.

Answer (score 3):

**Several members of the Kira Task force (that Light was in charge of), as well as Near's team, were present during the climax where**

> Light is exposed as Kira by Teru Mikami when Light's name is the only one not written in the Death Note.

The task force knew about Death Notes since

> Rem gave it to Kyosuke Higuchi and the task for caught him in possession of it

Which is revealed much earlier in the story.

Near realized Kira would likely use a catspaw to throw suspicion from himself so simply finding the person in physical possession of a Death Note wasn't enough.  He had to make sure he found the Death Note, and make Kira believe he'd won so he would show himself.

So Near

> Replaced the pages of the Death Note held by Teru Mikami (though Light was still the owner), and allowed Light to lure everyone to the creepy abandoned warehouse where Teru Mikami called Light "God" and wrote the names of everyone present, except Light.  Proving Light was actually Kira.

With Kira's real identity exposed, there was no reason to go hunting for other Kiras or other Death Notes - they had found the root cause.

Depending on if it's the manga/movies/anime Misa

> Kills herself, or it's heavily implied she does.

As for the task force, my guess is they continued working as an anti-Kira taskforce in some capacity, at least in the manga, because

> The manga ends with a group of Kira's followers praying for his return.

[Youtube link to the end with several characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccD_96pKAfI&ab_channel=purifyDBZ)